# Close a connection inside a HttpServlet inside a jetty 6 servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I have a javax HttpServlet inside a jetty servlet container (version 6.x.y of jetty), and I want to close the underlying connection after responding to some of the requests that are processed by this servlet.

What's the simplest way to achieve this? 
I've looked at the `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` objects which are passed to `HttpServlet#doPost(…)`, but they don't seem to provide access to the underlying TCP connection.

Comment: You can close the response output stream. `HttpServletResponse#getOutputStream().close()` That's as far as it goes. The container manages the connection. That's outside the scope of the servlet's responsibilities.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to close? You want to deny connections to a servlet so that it is not accessible after some time?

Comment: We have some connections that are very long lived and want an easy way to break some of them on the backend to help with balancing the number of connections each server handles.